# Context help button behaviour on CPropertySheet

Tags: mfc

The latest version of Microsoft Office uses property sheets that have the context help [?] button next to the close button:

[image]

When the context button is clicked it invokes the application's help rather than switching to 'context mode', by which I mean the arrow cursor with a question mark, i.e. there is no context help despite this being the context help button (or appears to be).

**I'm trying to recreate this behaviour in an property sheet derived from the MFC CPropertySheet**. So far I've had no luck. Ideally I'd like a click on this button to act in the same way as pressing F1, e.g. call directly on to the OnHelpInfo function.

**Can anyone tell me how this might be achieved?**

Comment: After some digging, ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND looks promising, where SC_CONTEXTHELP is the value of WPARAM. Needs further investigation.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, adding **ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND** to the message map and then processing **SC_CONTEXTHELP** in **OnSysCommand** did the trick.