# How to connect clicking on context help button with my custom action?

Tags: qt

I have a dialog with two buttons in the title bar: the context help button and the close button. How can I find out that the user clicked the context help button to perform my custom action? (I want to show some help page in the browser as in VS dialogs.)

I found a similar question, but how to do this with qt?
[Context help button behaviour on CPropertySheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298196/context-help-button-behaviour-on-cpropertysheet)

Update.
Now I use the code like this:

```
class MyHelper : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyHelper( QObject * parent = nullptr ) {
        qApp->installEventFilter( this );
    }

protected:
    virtual bool eventFilter( QObject * obj, QEvent * ev ) override {
        if ( ev->type() == QEvent::EnterWhatsThisMode ) {
            showHelp( QApplication::activeWindow() );
            return true;
        }
        return QObject::eventFilter( obj, ev );
    }

private:
    void showHelp( QWidget * sender ) {
        //TODO
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [QWidget::nativeEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#nativeEvent) is what you are looking for.

Comment: This help button is not cross-platform by itself, so you will need to write platform-specific code anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helped me to discover that the standard `qWindowsWndProc` transforms `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message with `wParam == SC_CONTEXTHELP` to `EnterWhatsThisMode` event and sends it to qApp.